# Camelcase using split( ) twice in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a function to split a sentence into words then split the words into characters and capitalize the first letter of each word. Yes it's homework and after many tries I can not get it to work. One thing tripping me up is using split() twice.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<head>
    <title>Sentence Case Conversion</title>
    <script type= "text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form name= "convertText">
        <p>Enter text to convert to sentence case:</p>
        <input type ="text" size ="120" name="userInput">
        </br>
        </br>

        <input name= "Submit" onclick= "sentenceCase()" value= "Convert Text" type= "button">
    </form>

        </br>
        </br>
        </br>

        <form name= "ouputText">
        <p>Here is your converted text:</p>
        <input type="text" size="120" name="result">
            <script type= "text/javascript">
            /* <![CDATA[ */
            function sentenceCase() {

                var userInput = document.forms[0].userInput.value;        //get user input
                var wordArray = userInput.split(" ");                     //split user input into individual words

                for (var i=0; i<wordArray.length; i++) { 
                     var characterArray = wordArray[i].split("");
                     characterArray[0].toUpperCase();
                     wordArray[i]=characterArray.join;
                }

            /* ]]> */
            </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use charAt[0].toUpperCase() once you've split to words

Comment: Thank you for doing most of your homework yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You're close:

```
> characterArray[0].toUpperCase();
```

That returns a value, it doesn't modify it in place

```
> wordArray[i]=characterArray.join;
```

`join` is a method, you have to call it. Also, it returns a value, it doesn't modify anything in place. You might consider using substring instead, but with the array you have:

```
var firstChar = characterArray.shift().toUpperCase();
var newWord = firstChar + characterArray.join('');
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

`toUpperCase()` can't modify your variable in place; it returns the capitalized string. So:

```
characterArray[0] = characterArray[0].toUpperCase();
```

... but you could just use `charAt()` and `substring()`, too:

```
wordArray[0] = wordArray[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + wordArray[0].substring(1);
```

... and then you have to actually call `join()`:

```
wordArray[i] = characterArray.join();
```

... and you'd probably want to pass that an empty string, or it'll default to a comma as a separator.

<sub>The fun way is `'hello world this is camel case'.replace(/\s(\S)/g, function($0, $1) { return $1.toUpperCase(); })`, though.</sub>

Comment: I thought null was the default separator.

Comment: @Blazemonger: Try it: `['Hello', ' world!'].join()`

Answer (score 1):

Factor out the common elements into understandable pieces of code:

```
function toCamelCase(sentence) {
    var words = sentence.split(" ");
    var length = words.length;

    for (var i = 1; i < length; i++)
        words[i] = capitalize(words[i]);
    return words.join("");
}

function capitalize(word) {
    return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
}
```

Now you can convert sentences to upper case. It's probably a good idea to remove punctuation marks from the sentence before converting it. Here are a few examples:

```
alert(toCamelCase("java script")); // javaScript
alert(toCamelCase("json to XML")); // jsonToXML
alert(toCamelCase("ECMA script")); // ECMAScript
```

The last one appears to be PascalCase but is still considered valid camelCase. You can see the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/GhKmf/